# Unable to receive UDP broadcast packets on PPP connection

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ppp, dial-up

I am struggling for two days now with no success. I have two modems (do not ask, some special stuff), that uses dial up (PPP) connection. I tried this on windows XP and it works like a charm. I am sending unicast and broadcast UPD packets. If I repeat that on Windows 7 i can send only unicast data, broadcast packets seems to be lost somewhere. I tried to use Microsoft Network Monitor and I can see that broadcasted packets are being received on my PPP connection. But after that, they are gone. Somewhere in the kernel. I truly do not understand why. I disabled firewall, antivirus, base filtering engine, tried to log dropped packed in [Windows Filtering Platform](http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2009/01/08/the-windows-filtering-platform-has-blocked-a-bind-to-a-local-port.aspx), tried clean WIN7 machine and all that with no success.

Here is a sample packet received on interface, but it has newer reach my app:

```
    No.     Time               Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 13:20:56.093380000 192.168.1.50          192.168.1.255         UDP      49     Source port: x11  Destination port: x11

Frame 1: 49 bytes on wire (392 bits), 49 bytes captured (392 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: May  7, 2014 13:20:56.093380000 Central Europe Daylight Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1399461656.093380000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 49 bytes (392 bits)
    Capture Length: 49 bytes (392 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:data:vssmonitoring]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: ae:4e:20:00:01:00 (ae:4e:20:00:01:00), Dst: Xerox_00:00:00 (01:00:01:00:00:00)
    Destination: Xerox_00:00:00 (01:00:01:00:00:00)
        Address: Xerox_00:00:00 (01:00:01:00:00:00)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address (multicast/broadcast)
    Source: ae:4e:20:00:01:00 (ae:4e:20:00:01:00)
        Address: ae:4e:20:00:01:00 (ae:4e:20:00:01:00)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50), Dst: 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 34
    Identification: 0x0032 (50)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 126
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xb817 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50)
    Destination: 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: x11 (6001), Dst Port: x11 (6001)
    Source port: x11 (6001)
    Destination port: x11 (6001)
    Length: 14
    Checksum: 0xafd1 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Data (6 bytes)

0000  34 34 34 34 34 34                                 444444
    Data: 343434343434
    [Length: 6]
VSS-Monitoring ethernet trailer, Source Port: 127
    Src Port: 127
```

I am running out of my ideas, if anyone could help, with any idea, please do. I am not sure if this feature is dropped in win7 or not.

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Sure. As a testing tool I am using Hercules tool http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html. I am using it to test UDP communication. On both side I opened 6001 port and I am sending the udp packets across. If I send them by unicasting, the data a very well received inside hercules tool. If I a sending them by broadcast address 192.168.1.255 I can see on network monitor tool, that they are received over my PPP connection. The problem is, that I do not receive them in Hercules tool. I tried to build my own code, the result was the same. Somehow data from interface are just lost.